# Restore the Thieves guild - Special Mission in Solutide

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I seem to be having some trouble getting to the special mission in Solutide.

I've been keeping count, multiple times, of the number of missions I've been doing for Vex and Delvin.

At the moment I've got a count of 13 solitude missions. 5 of those for Vex, 5 for Delvin, and the other 8 were a mix (I wasn't tracking whether it was a Vex or Delvin mission at that point).

I'm yet to receive the special mission for Solutide and it seems to be going on forever.

Is this a bug or have I missed something fundamental?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a glitch, and you aren't the first one to experience it.

If you are on the PC, you can force the quest to start by using this console command:

> setstage TGTQ02 10

Answer (score -3):

The key is you need to do 5 jobs in each city, then you'll get a bonus for that city (something unlocked for the thieves guild.)

Unfortunately if your unsure which cities you've done, you will need to start counting now. What I did was go to Devlin and get a mission from him, then go to Vex and keep declining the mission (accept and then decline) until I got one for the same city. Upon my return I'd do this again to get two more for the same city.

Once you've done enough for all the cities you'll then be able to continue with the "questline".

Source: (Spoiler warning) - http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thieves_Guild_%28Skyrim%29#City_Influence_Quests

Comment: I've done 5 jobs in all of the cities. I've completed the special missions in all cities except for Solitude. This is the only city that I never seem to get a special mission for.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't help anymore. I thought I'd done them all, and then it unlocked after I did two more quests in solitude. I presumed at the time I'd counted wrong.

Comment: Love to know why this is -2....